# How to set a position of a popup to a desired location when clicked on link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

When I click on a link a pop up is displayed but not a desired location. My question is how to set it at a particular location? My code is:

```
function showPopupforAssignSubject(id)
    {

        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        
        $("#assign_subjects_"+id).jqpopup_open("OpenDivforAssign");
        
        
        }); 
    }
```

I have used a third party js in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this function but ... maybe

```
$("#assign_subjects_"+id).css('top', '20px');
$("#assign_subjects_"+id).css('left', '100px');
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the documentation : http://jqframework.com/jqpopup

The jqpopup doesn't support any method that would give let you set a location. It seems to have a `jqpopup_toTop()` and `jqpopup_toCenter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the example in firebug, and it appears to append `"_p"` to the end of your div's ID.

So this will work

```
  $("#assign_subjects").jqpopup_open("OpenDivforAssign");
  //set the top left postion of the popup
  $("#assign_subjects_p").css({top:'100px', left:'800px'});
```

Otherwise, this plugin only seems to support toTop(), and toCenter().   I would recommend using a plugin that gives you greater flexibility, such as [jquery ui's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead of this.